# Spark Stats on a array that has some nulls

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark

I have the following code:

```
            myData3 = myData.map(lambda line: line.split(',')).map(lambda fields: ("Column", float(fields[0]))).map(lambda (column, value) : (value)).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

I put the if statement in there because right now I have a few datasets that have entire column. The float(fields[0]) mapping causes errors when it runs into anything that is null. How do I write spark code that will allow me to take an example array: [1,2,3,4,,5,,19] and process it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run a filter before your map:

```
.map(...split...)
.filter(lambda fields: fields[0] != null)
.map(...process...)
```

You can use an [accumulator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html#accumulators) to keep track of the filtered out data if you really want, also.

With the accumulator it would look more like (python is not my usual language, so it might be off by a little:

```
accum = sc.accumulator(0)

def filterWithAccum(fields):
  accum.add(1)
  return fields[0] != null

.map(...split...)
.filter(filterWithAccum)
.map(...process...)
```

Comment: Great thanks on more question for you, I have the following function happening: myData = dataSplit.map(lambda arr: (arr[lines]))\
            .map(lambda line: line.split(','))\
            .map(lambda fields: ("Column", fields[0]))\
            .map(lambda (column, value) : value)\
            .filter(lambda line : line != u'')\
            .map(lambda (value) : float(value))\
            .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK) 
How would I add to my accumulator during that filter line. I've tried a few things that havent worked.

Comment: @user148165 I updated my answer. If you want the entire field added to a list, then you will need to subclass AccumulatorParam (the docs cover this well)

Comment: If this helped you, please don't forget to upvote and/or accept as the answer.